# Google Maps API Android - NullPointerException - setBoundsInParent

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

In our Android mobile application (compatible with Android versions 4.0 and upper), we use Google Maps API V2.

We get some bug reports from users on some kinds of devices (Android versions 4.3, 4.4 and 5.0) with a NullPointerException in setBoundsInParent method of android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo class.

The application crashes when the user tries to move or to zoom on the map.

The problem only appears for some users - devices. Most of our customers do not have that problem.

**The problem seems to come from the use of the setPadding method of Google Maps API to position the Google logo so that it is always clearly visible on the map** :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
                ... 
        // Initialize map
        ...     
        // Sets the padding for the map
                if(mMap!=null)
                {
                     mMap.setPadding(0, DPI.toPixels(100), 0, DPI.toPixels(100));
                }
                ...
}
```

Removing the call to the setPadding method seems to resolve the problem for affected users but it is not a valid solution for us because we need to position the Google logo with this method.

We cannot reproduce this problem on our development devices, so it's difficult for us to find the real origin of this problem.

You will find the full stacktraces of the bug below.

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks a lot in advance for your answer.

Best regards.

**Stacktrace on Android 4.3 - 4.4**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.setBoundsInParent(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:1012)
at android.support.v4.view.a.k.c(SourceFile:819)
at android.support.v4.view.a.i.b(SourceFile:1850)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.et.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.widget.ab.a(SourceFile:56)
at android.support.v4.widget.ac.a(SourceFile:717)
at android.support.v4.view.a.x.a(SourceFile:112)
at android.support.v4.view.a.ad.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(SourceFile:42)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:724)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:147)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$300(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:49)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:971)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Stacktrace on Android 5.0**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.graphics.Rect.left' on a null object reference
at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.setBoundsInParent(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:1316)
at android.support.v4.view.a.k.c(SourceFile:819)
at android.support.v4.view.a.i.b(SourceFile:1850)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.et.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.widget.ab.a(SourceFile:56)
at android.support.v4.widget.ac.a(SourceFile:717)
at android.support.v4.view.a.x.a(SourceFile:112)
at android.support.v4.view.a.ad.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(SourceFile:42)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:894)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:155)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$400(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:53)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1236)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Attempt to read from field 'int android.graphics.Rect.left' on a null object reference. Check your codes(setBoundsInParent(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:1012)) or attach them

Comment: Thank you, however, this class is not in our code but in the code of an Android library.

Comment: You have to check your codes, perhaps you are using main UI to do some heavy tasks

Comment: Check your code at parameter `int android.graphics.Rect.left`, because it gets null object.

Comment: The bug has been confirmed by Google : https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7619

Comment: @Patrick-GeolivesSA Post your comment as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug has been confirmed by Google : http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7619

Best regards.